# How an infringement in a qualification method would affect a product?

Tags: patent-infringement, infringement, legal

Let's have the following hypothetical case:

- Company develops a product using method 'X' for some testing procedure qualifying it.
- Company releases product, development is frozen, testing no longer takes place, product sells.
- Someone raises an infringement claim over method 'X'.

What this case? The product as-is doesn't incorporate method 'X', it was only used in its development process, so technically the infringement doesn't take place at the time the claim is raised.

What if the product had some qualification based on its development and testing process incorporating method 'X'? Could this revoke that qualification? (maybe this is a bit ridiculous to expect, just for completeness)

Of course it may be possible if necessary to implement a different, non-infringing method for testing then, but this is just the same case like any ordinary patent infringement case.

Comment: Can you clarify "qualification" ? Is the method done once at design time or is it ongoing during production?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Design time. Think of a software product for a trivial example.

Comment: I found 35 U.S. Code § 271(g)
(g)Whoever without authority imports into the United States or offers to sell, sells, or uses within the United States a product which is made by a process patented in the United States shall be liable as an infringer, . . . This talks about a product made by a patent process. I do not know if this would apply to a product whose design was tested by a patented product.

Comment: It occurred to me I might misunderstand the question. Is the hypothetical use of this patented testing tool, itself, an infringement or was the tool legitimately bought/licensed?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I assumed there was no third-party tool used, rather that for example a small firm in some European country developed and used a process without knowing it was patented (maybe even only in the US if it was software). The US law might apply here, the ambiguous part is "made by a patent process" as you mention: the testing itself isn't necessary for the actual production, only for the original design, assisting and qualifying the design itself.

Comment: A patent that might exist in a European country would not affect the status of something that is used, made, sold, or imported into the U.S. Only a U.S. patent would be relevant at all. Here is a link to a discussion that might be relevant. http://www.finnegan.com/resources/articles/articlesdetail.aspx?news=c9459d08-6491-4e06-8ab2-aa12db3045b7.  If you were my cousin I'd tell you not to worry.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite No, I meant the other way around. That for example in Europe a company was developing a product, using software methods for testing, not even really doing any patent research (as it might not even contain anything which would be patentable by an European country's laws). Then when attempting to sell the finished product in the US, they would face an infringement claim on the testing method used only during development within Europe. Anyway, this goes a little beyond my original question (which considers the case when the patent exists within the country).

Comment: The courts are doing strange things things these days but it is hard to imagine that being touched by a U.S. patented method that was performed out of the U.S.,during design and validation time would keep your product from being imported into and sold and used in the U.S. But, this is very much not a legal opinion.